# XAML datepicker to only return date but not time

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker

I wanted to return just the date (not the time), but I have tried everything and it always returns

```
7/23/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

but I only want

```
7/23/2013
```

Here's my code, and it needs to be done in pure XAML.

```
            <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding myDateProperty}" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,1,5,1" Name="ObsoleteDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110">
           <DatePicker.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                 <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate>
                          <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}"/>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
              </Style>
           </DatePicker.Resources>
        </DatePicker>
```

Comment: where do you want just the date? on ui or in your viewmodel? did you try SelectedDateFormat?

Comment: in the viewmodel. Tried SelectedDateFormat="Short" but same result.

Comment: "12:00:00" is the default value, you can just use the Date part if you don't care for the time: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx

Comment: can you pls show your viewmodel code. you can always use a converter to get what you want

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextBox Background="#fff" x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}, StringFormat=d}" />
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use `StringFormat=d` in place of `StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}`

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code and it worked for me.(`ObsoleteDate` is the name of your `DatePicker`)

```
ObsoleteDate.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()
```